# What do `use raw` and `raw: raw::git_buf` from the git2-rs wrapper mean?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to build a safe wrapper over some native Rust-C bindings. I'm referencing the [git2-rs](https://github.com/alexcrichton/git2-rs/blob/739ae40aefb292ec72daa11ad9f33ed458a2afa8/src/buf.rs) codebase and I ran into the following usage:

```
use raw;
use util::Binding;
pub struct Buf {
    raw: raw::git_buf,
}
```

What are `use raw` and `raw: raw::git_buf` doing? I think this has to do with `std::raw`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`raw` is [the identifier that git2-rs chooses to give to the libgit2_sys crate](https://github.com/alexcrichton/git2-rs/blob/739ae40aefb292ec72daa11ad9f33ed458a2afa8/src/lib.rs#L73):

```
extern crate libgit2_sys as raw;
```

`use raw` is thus equivalent to `use libgit2_sys` and conceptually the same as `use regex` or `use itertools` — it simply brings the crate into scope in this module.

Please re-read [Bringing Paths into Scope with the use Keyword](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-04-bringing-paths-into-scope-with-the-use-keyword.html) from [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/foreword.html) for a refresher on the `use` statement.

`raw: raw::git_buf` defines the field `raw` of the struct `Buf` to be of the type `raw::git_buf`. This is equivalent to `raw: libgit2_sys::git_buf` and conceptually the same as `raw: String` or `raw: i32`.

Please re-read [Defining and Instantiating Structs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html) for a refresher on how structs are defined.

Comment: Just one more clarification. `raw::git_buf` is the same as `libgit2_sys::git_buf`?